# Realigning the Cursor in a Container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently making a game for a project and added a "flashlight" effect over the top of the game.
See: https://codemyui.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Flashlight-Mouse-Pointer.gif

The problem is that the torchlight does not align with the cursor, which is way over to the left of the screen. Blue circle is the cursor's rough position to highlight the issue.[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9NqE.png)

I couldn't find much in the way of re-aligning the cursor on a container. I have a suspicion that it is the JS that is causing the issue but I don't know for certain. Any ideas?

Here is the relevant code:

```js
//game flashlight
function update(e) {
  var x = e.clientX || e.touches[0].clientX
  var y = e.clientY || e.touches[0].clientY

  let gameBox = document.getElementById('gameBox');
  gameBox.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px');
  gameBox.style.setProperty('--cursorY', y + 'px');
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)
```

```css
#gameContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1100px;
  float: right;
}

#gameContent {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 1050px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFE29C;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#gameBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #EABF7D;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 12% 0 12%;
  line-height: 1em;
}


/* Flashlight Overlay */

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  cursor: auto;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}

.image-container .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%);
}

#mapFit {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer">
  <div id="gameContent">
    <div id="gameBox" class="image-container">
      <img id="mapFit" src="images/Temple_Escape.jpg" alt="main map">
      <img id="chest" src="images/chest.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="chestOpened" src="images/chestopened.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="gold1" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold1Click()">
      <img id="gold2" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold2Click()">
      <img id="gold3" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold3Click()">
      <img id="gold4" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold4Click()">
      <img id="gold5" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold5Click()">
      <img id="gold6" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold6Click()">
      <img id="podium" src="images/podium.png" alt="main map" onclick="podiumClick()">
      <img id="rope" src="images/rope.png" alt="main map" onclick="ropeClick()">
      <img id="skeleton" src="images/skeleton.png" alt="main map" onclick="skeletonClick()">
      <img id="brokenPickaxe" src="images/brokenpickaxe.png" alt="main map" onclick="pickaxeClick()">
      <img id="stoneSlab1" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab1Click()">
      <img id="stoneSlab2" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab2Click()">
      <img id="tile1" src="images/tile1.png" alt="main map" onclick="floorStoneClick()">
      <img id="door1" src="images/door1.png" alt="main map" onclick="exitDoorClick()">
      <img id="redOrb" src="images/redorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="blueOrb" src="images/blueorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="greenOrb" src="images/greenorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <div class="after"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT: Also another issue unrelated to the pointer, I cannot click on the images inside the game whilst the flashlight is overlaid on top of the map. This is probably an issue to do with the placement of div id="after". Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `getBoundingClientRect`

```
function update(e) {
  let gameBox = document.getElementById("gameBox");
  const bounds = gameBox.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.pageX - bounds.left - window.scrollX;
  const y = e.pageY - bounds.top - window.scrollY;
  gameBox.style.setProperty("--cursorX", x + "px");
  gameBox.style.setProperty("--cursorY", y + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `getBoundingClientRect()` of the target element and then subtract that from your `event.clientX` position to get the proper position of your mouse within the element.

Use `pointer-events: none;` to allow your mouse to ***click through*** your `flashlight element` to the underlying elements.

---

### EDIT:

***Note on your second question...***

Your code is looking for the event.target for the ***mouseover*** and ***mouseout*** events, so when you add `pointer-events: none`, this now creates an event target for the child elements when they are hovered over, which are your **img** tags. The issue is that now the equation subtracting the client cords with the client bounding coords will change due to the target changing. So to alleviate this, you will need logic that accommodates for the children in relation to your parent element which is the relative compartment for finding where the ***flashlight*** element is located on the page.

So a fix is to add a class to your img tags `class="img"` then run a conditional to make sure the elements you are firing your event on are either the parent or its img children...

So, add a conditional to check the `event.target.id` is ***gameBox*** or `classList.contains('img')` each of these conditionals will be different: The parent element when ***mouseover*** will be `e.target.getBoundingClientRect()` and `e.clientX/Y` and subtract those to get the cursor position within the parent element, while the `e.target.classLists.contains('img')` conditional will get the parentNode of the ***e.target*** and then  `e.target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()` and subtract it from the `e.clientX/Y`. So no matter the ***mouseover*** event, it will get the proper coords and display the flashlight coords in the element properly, while allowing you to click through using `pointer-events:none` css rule.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img')
const gameBox = document.getElementById('gameBox')
let rect, x, y = '';
//game flashlight
// default spot in middle
x = gameBox.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
y = gameBox.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;
gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorX`, `${x}px`);
gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorY`, `${y}px`);

const update = (e) => {
  if (e.target.id === "gameBox") {
    rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorX`, `${x}px`);
    gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorY`, `${y}px`);
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains('img')) {
    imgs.forEach((img) => {
      rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      x = e.clientX - e.target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      y = e.clientY - e.target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorX`, `${x}px`);
      gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorY`, `${y}px`);
    })
  } else {          
      gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorX`, `${x}px`);
      gameBox.style.setProperty(`--cursorY`, `${y}px`);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove', update)
```

```css
#gameContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1100px;
  display: flex;
}

img:hover~.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#gameContent {
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 1050px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #FFE29C;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#gameBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #EABF7D;
  border-color: #E1AA72;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 12% 0 12%;
  line-height: 1em;
}


/* Flashlight Overlay */

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  cursor: auto;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}

.image-container .after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient( circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .95) 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#mapFit {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  height: 768px;
  width: 768px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer">
  <div id="gameContent">
    <div id="gameBox" class="image-container">
      <img id="mapFit" class="img" src="images/Temple_Escape.jpg" alt="main map">
      <img id="chest" class="img" src="images/chest.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="chestOpened" class="img" src="images/chestopened.png" alt="main map" onclick="chestClick()">
      <img id="gold1" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold1Click()">
      <img id="gold2" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold2Click()">
      <img id="gold3" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold3Click()">
      <img id="gold4" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold4Click()">
      <img id="gold5" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold5Click()">
      <img id="gold6" class="img" src="images/gold.png" alt="main map" onclick="gold6Click()">
      <img id="podium" class="img" src="images/podium.png" alt="main map" onclick="podiumClick()">
      <img id="rope" class="img" src="images/rope.png" alt="main map" onclick="ropeClick()">
      <img id="skeleton" class="img" src="images/skeleton.png" alt="main map" onclick="skeletonClick()">
      <img id="brokenPickaxe" class="img" src="images/brokenpickaxe.png" alt="main map" onclick="pickaxeClick()">
      <img id="stoneSlab1" class="img" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab1Click()">
      <img id="stoneSlab2" class="img" src="images/stoneslab.png" alt="main map" onclick="slab2Click()">
      <img id="tile1" class="img" src="images/tile1.png" alt="main map" onclick="floorStoneClick()">
      <img id="door1" class="img" src="images/door1.png" alt="main map" onclick="exitDoorClick()">
      <img id="redOrb" class="img" src="images/redorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="blueOrb" class="img" src="images/blueorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <img id="greenOrb" class="img" src="images/greenorb.png" alt="main map" onclick="">
      <div class="after"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```